# Bootstrap 4 beta - how to display div for sm only?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In Bootstrap alpha 6 I could write this, to have a div's contents only show for sm:

```
<div class="hidden-md-up hidden-xs-down">
   This would only show for sm in Bootstrap 4 alpha 6.
</div>
```

This no longer works in the Bootstrap 4 beta.

How can I show a div's content for sm only, using bootstrap 4 beta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [display](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/) properties.

```
<div class="d-xl-none d-lg-none d-md-none d-sm-block d-xs-none">This would only show for sm</div>
```

This will show the div for `sm` only.

Comment: I believe the correct thing would be to add all these three classes: d-none d-md-block d-lg-none

Comment: I updated my answer to include `xl` and `lg`. That should work on all screen sizes so only `sm` is visible.

Comment: Didn't you forget the xs? I mean you should hide the xs, if only showing sm.

Comment: The docs don't mention `xs` as far as I can tell...but maybe that was an oversight.

Comment: Yes "xs" works.  So... “hidden-md-down” was replaced with “d-xl-block d-lg-block d-md-none d-sm-none d-xs-none” (then buried in the documentation, as punishment from the Bootstrap gods for side-by-side identical divs and probably other impure thoughts).

Comment: @styfle Correction!  .d-xs-none does NOT in fact exist.  My apologies... I'll update my comment when allowed.

Comment: @styflt The missing .d-xs-none class seems to be a Beta1 design bug. See github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23475

Answer (score 1):

@styfle was right to use [display properties](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/). But keep in mind it's all mobile first, so start with `xs` and then go up with `md`, `lg`...

**If we only want to display in `sm`:**

- First we do not want to have it in `xs` so we need to drop it there with `d-none` (think of its scope as `@media (min-width: 0px)`).
- Second we want to have it in `sm` so display it there with `d-sm-block` (scope: `@media (min-width: 576px)`).
- Third we do not want to have it in `md` so drop it there with `d-md-none` (scope: `@media (min-width: 768px)`),
- (Fourth, no more necessary, as `d-md-none` already scopes cases for `lg` and `xl`.)

So altogether we get:

```
<div class="d-none d-sm-block d-md-none">
   This would only show for sm in Bootstrap 4 Beta
</div>
```

**Another example:**
Display only in `sm` and `lg`.

```
<div class="d-none d-sm-block d-md-none d-lg-block d-xl-none">
    This would only show for sm and lg in Bootstrap 4 Beta
</div>
```